# Lists of data (plugins for website) - pick grouped unique rows and order by highest column

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, vba

I have rows of data that look like this:

```
Date                Site name       Plugin name                 Version
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
27/08/2020 12:52    PRD site.com    Advanced Custom Fields PRO  5.8.7
28/08/2020 13:13    PRD site.com    Advanced Custom Fields PRO  5.90
20/08/2020 12:52    PRD site.com    Advanced Custom Fields PRO  5.9.10
29/08/2020 13:13    PRD site.com    Advanced Custom Fields PRO  5.9.12
28/08/2020 15:32    PRD site.com    Quadrant Radar Chart        1.2
```

I'd like to create a formula (if possible) that groups all the "Advanced Custom Fields PRO" rows together and outputs on one, the highest number in version (last column).

```
Date                Site name       Plugin name                 Version
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
29/08/2020 13:13    PRD site.com    Advanced Custom Fields PRO  5.9.12
28/08/2020 15:32    PRD site.com    Quadrant Radar Chart        1.2
```

Is this even possible? Should I be looking at VBA? I come from a web developer background and this is easy in SQL - not so easy in Excel?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why is 5.9.12 considered as the highest version instead of 5.90?

Comment: typo - should be 5.9.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. On the ribbon, click on Data -> From Table/Range. Select your table, check "My table has headers". This will be you table when Power Query Editor opens:

[image: IMG:]

2. On the power query editor, select Group by, then Advanced. Select "Plugin name". Enter "Version" on New column name; select `Max` on the Operation dropbox; select Version on the Column dropbox. Click Add aggregation. Add for Date and Site name, select Min for Operation and select their respective columns. Click OK.

[image: IMG:]

You will get this:

[image: IMG:]

Extend the formula bar, re-order the column as shown here. Enter them manually so their order reflect your desire output: "Date", "Site name", etc. You will obtain this:

[image: IMG:]

Click on Close & Load. A new sheet will be created with this result:

[image: IMG:]

Comment: Thank you - works great